# Deprecated classes in Azure SDK 2.5

Tags: c#, azure

We are currently working on uppgrading our Azure SDK version from 2.2 to 2.5 that is the latest at the moment.

When I do this I notice that the following classes is marked as deprecated:
`DeploymentDiagnosticManager`
`DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration`
`DiagnosticMonitor`

When I go into the MSDN page about these classes it stands nothing out of the ordinary.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.diagnostics.diagnosticmonitorconfiguration.aspx

Does anyone know what I am supposed to use for diagnostics now when these classes are deprecated?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When looking at the [Breaking Changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn873976.aspx#BKMK_breaking) of the Azure SDK for .NET 2.5 Release Notes:

> **Diagnostics configuration in code is no longer supported** - With the Azure SDK version 2.5, all diagnostics configuration must be done in the XML configuration file diagnostics.wadcfgx. Any previous code-based diagnostics configuration (for example, using the DiagnosticMonitor API) must be migrated to the diagnostics.wadcfgx file. Code used to configure crash dumps in previous SDKs must also be migrated to the diagnostics.wadcfgx file.